# Using grep to get the next WORD after a match in each line

Tags: linux, grep

I want to get the "**GET**" queries from my server logs.

For example, this is the server log

```
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [10/Jun/2012 15:32:27] code 404, message File not fo$
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [10/Jun/2012 15:32:27] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 404 -   
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [10/Jun/2012 15:41:57] code 404, message File not fo$
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [10/Jun/2012 15:41:57] "GET /ss HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

When I try with simple grep or awk,

```
Adi:~ adi$ awk '/GET/, /HTTP/' serverlogs.txt
```

it gives out

```
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [10/Jun/2012 15:32:27] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 404 -
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [10/Jun/2012 15:41:57] "GET /ss HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I just want to display : **hello** and **ss**

Is there any way this could be done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming you have gnu grep, you can use perl-style regex to do a positive lookbehind:

```
grep -oP '(?<=GET\s/)\w+' file
```

If you don't have gnu grep, then I'd advise just using sed:

```
sed -n '/^.*GET[[:space:]]\{1,\}\/\([-_[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\).*$/s//\1/p' file
```

If you happen to have gnu sed, that can be greatly simplified:

```
sed -n '/^.*GET\s\+\/\(\w\+\).*$/s//\1/p' file
```

The bottom line here is, you certainly don't need pipes to accomplish this.  `grep` or `sed` alone will suffice.

Comment: Sed works like `/s/one/two/g` having 4 slashes. With `/^.*GET\s\+\/\(\w\+\).*$/s//\1/p` you have 5 slashes and `s`between. What is `s` here?

Comment: @Timo `What is s here?` `s` there is a sed substitution command. The `/regex/` is a matching command - it executes the command after `/regex/` only if the line matches. So `s` command is executed only if `/^.*GET\s\+\/\(\w\+\).*$/` mathces. Then empty regex reuses last regex, so `s//` is equal to `s/^.*GET\s\+\/\(\w\+\).*$/`. It get's replaced by `\1`, so by first matching group, ie. `\(\w\+\)`. The `p` flag for `s` command causes the replacement to be printed if the `s` command was successful. For more information, see https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html and posix sed manual.

Answer (score 12):

In this case since the log file has a known structure, one option is to use [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) to pull out the 7th column (fields are denoted by tabs by default).

```
grep GET log.txt | cut -f 7
```

Comment: Still showing out the entire line.

1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [10/Jun/2012 15:32:27] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 404 -

1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [10/Jun/2012 15:41:57] "GET /ss HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Hmmm, is it space or tab separated?  If space, use `-d' '` with cut to specify space as the column delimiter.

Comment: Works great with the **-d ' '** parameter.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to do this and came across this link: https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/153101-print-next-word-after-found-pattern.html

Summary:
use grep to find matching lines, then use awk to find the pattern and print the next field:

```
grep pattern logfile | \
  awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i~/pattern/) print $(i+1)}'
```

If you want to know the unique occurrences:

```
grep pattern logfile | \
  awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i~/pattern/) print $(i+1)}' | \
  sort | \
  uniq -c
```

Answer (score 4):

use a pipe if you use grep:

```
grep -o /he.* log.txt | grep -o [^/].*
grep -o /ss log.txt | grep -o [^/].*
```

[^/] means extract the letters after ^ symbol from the grep output

Answer (score 3):

It's often easier to use a pipeline rather than a single complex regular expression. This works on the data you provided:

```
fgrep GET /tmp/foo | 
    egrep -o 'GET (.*) HTTP' |
    sed -r 's/^GET \/(.+) HTTP/\1/'
```

This pipeline returns the following results:

```
hello
ss
```

There are certainly other ways to get the job done, but this patently works on the provided corpus.

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk '{match($7,/\/(\w+)/,a);} length(a[1]){print a[1]}' log.txt
hello
ss
```

If you have `gawk` then above command will use `match` function to select the desired value using regex and storing it to an array `a`.