# Extract next word in a space-delimited string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

This seems like a pretty popular question, but for some reason the awk solution I found here that I am trying does not work.

I have an alias that gets the info on some of my devices on my network. I want to be able to search the list and retrieve the device "name". The alias and output look like:

```
$ mtb devices
Alias     Address           Name         Software   Brand
------------------------------------------------------------
          192.168.1.107     Device1      1009       Some_brand
TV        192.168.1.103     Device2      0831       Some_other_brand
TV2       192.168.1.105     Device3      0831       Some_brand
```

In my script, using grep I can take the line I am looking for, since I search by the ip address:

```
IP=$1
BOX=`mtb devices | grep ${IP}`
echo $BOX
```

This gives me a result:

```
$ ./my_devices.sh 192.168.1.105
TV2 192.168.1.105 Device3 0831 Some_brand
```

Now I want to get the "Name" from the line, so I used awk '{print $3}':

```
IP=$1
BOX=`mtb devices | grep ${IP} | awk '{print $3;}'`
echo $BOX
```

```
$ ./my_devices.sh 192.168.1.105
Device3
```

But when I search an IP address that does not have an alias, then I obviously get the wrong result:

```
$ ./my_devices.sh 192.168.1.107
1009
```

I looked for more soltions and I found another awk solution, but the new awk is not working:

```
IP=$1
BOX=`mtb devices | grep ${IP} | awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "$IP") print $(i+1) }'`
echo $BOX
```

When I run my script it returns nothing:

```
$ ./my_devices.sh 192.168.1.105
$
```

Obviously I want it to return `Device3`.

The IP address field and Name fields will always be populated, but the alias field may not be populated.

Comment: `1)` instead of tildes, use this syntax: `BOX=$( command )` . `2)` your last awk will work if you pass the variable as expected: `mtb devices | awk -v ip="$IP" '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == ip) print $(i+1) }'` (also omit `grep`, only one command is enough for this, either grep or awk or sed etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using grep to get the next WORD after a match in each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971765/using-grep-to-get-the-next-word-after-a-match-in-each-line)

Comment: I've never heard of `mtb` but most tools that can produce output in a human-readable table also have options to produce the output in a more easily machine-readable format - have you checked the man page for `mtb` to see if it has such options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one observation holds for all output from `mtb devices`, the device name could be references as
(number of fields) - 2

```
IP=$1
BOX=`mtb devices | grep ${IP} | awk '{ print $(NF - 2); }'`
echo $BOX
```

or a shortened alternate:

```
mtb devices | awk "/$1/ { print \$(NF - 2); }"
```

Comment: Love this, but there should be spaces around `$IP` so that 1.2.3.4 doesn't also pick up 1.2.3.40...

Answer (score 1):

1st solution considers that you want to print next field whether IP address is found. 2nd solution looks for header of Input_file and checks which field has string `Name` in it and then prints it, so this will be more generic as even Name is present in any field it will print it.

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following. One need to run this script by giving ip address as an argument to script.

```
cat script.ksh
arg="$1"
mtb devices | 
awk -v ip="$arg" '
{
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    if(j==ip){
       print $(j+1)
    }
  }
}'
```

---

---

***2nd solution(Generic solution):*** OR in case you want to get the `Name` field column number from very first line then following may help you.

```
cat script.ksh
arg="$1"
mtb devices |
awk -v ip="$arg" '
FNR==1{
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    if($j=="Name"){
       field=j
    }
  }
}
{
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    if(j==ip){
       print $field
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   read -p "enter ip: " ip
fi

awk -v ip="$ip" "/ip/{if (NF==5) {print $3}}" <<< $(mtb devices)
```

DR;TL

For IP (192.168.1.107) there is no name, **you can check fields count very easily** using special variable in awk called **"NF"**

```sh
mtb devices | grep '192\.168.\1\.107' | awk '{if (NF==5) {print $3}}'
```

This won't print anything.

```sh
mtb devices | grep '192\.168\.1\.103' | awk '{if (NF==5) {print $3}}'
```

This will print **Device2**

Note: when using regular expression keep in mind that dot character (.) represents any character, it's better to **escape** it like: \.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like `awk`, there's always `sed`:

```sh
mtb devices | sed -ne "s/.*192.168.1.107\s*\(\w\+\).*/\1/p" 
# or
mtb devices | sed -ne "s/.*$IP\s*\(\w\+\).*/\1/p"
```

This will `-n`ot print any lines unless the `-e`xpression tells us otherwise. Our expression is `s//p`, which does `s/`ubstitution, and `/p`rints the result.

If we do substitute, we grab the `.*`whole line`.*`, capture the next `\w`ord after our variable, and then replace our whole grabbed line with just the `\1` group that we captured.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, `grep` is awesome, but when I need to do slightly more complex matching and cropping, I turn to `sed` to avoid spawning needless processes.

```
mtb devices | sed -En "/ $IP /{ s/^.* $IP +(\\S+) .*/\\1/; p; }"
```

No `awk` needed. `/ $IP /` replaces the `grep`, `s/^.* $IP +(\\S+) .*/\\1/` strips everything else off the line, leaving the field following the IP. `-n` prevents printing unless asked, and `p` asks. `-E` keeps me from having to use a ton of backslash quoting, though since I embedded the `$IP` I still need an extra `\` in `\\1`.

I actually wrote it with `\s` & `\S` and it worked, with AND without the extra `\`, but I'm on an emulation. Test it on your environment.