# shell grep regex matching pattern

Tags: shell, grep

I have file with text as below, I would like get the the version argument, 123abc in below case, the argument can be alphanumric.

```
sometext -version 123abc -mode xx
```

Not working:

```
grep -oP "\S+\s+-version\s+\K(.*)\s+" file
```

Comment: Why not `grep -oP 'version\s+\K\S+' file`? Does your `grep` support PCRE? what do you mean by "not working"? No result, or you get `123abc -mode`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using grep to get the next WORD after a match in each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971765/using-grep-to-get-the-next-word-after-a-match-in-each-line)

Comment: What would you like to do with `sometext -version "123 abc" ...` or `sometext -version 123\ abc` or `sometext -version "abc123"` or `sometext -version 'abc123'` or `sometext -version \n\t\r123` or ... Parsing text like this is extremely fragile, and my guess is that you have a problem at a different level.  Rather than scraping the information out of this file, create a single source of truth for the version and use that to generate this file.

Answer (score 0):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/.*-version  *\([^ ]*\).*/\1/' file
123abc
```

Trying to use `grep -P` to select parts of input lines other than the matching string is just overly complicated IMHO as well as being non-portable.